# Codeigniter - Get the value of Checkboxes and display it on the another page

Tags: codeigniter

I am a newbie here in code igniter, i'm having a problem of getting all the checked values in my checkboxes, and i don't know how to display it on the other view ...

here's my code

View

```html
<?php foreach($sen_votes as $sen) { ?>
  <?php echo form_open("votation/balot_form"); ?>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <center><div class="featurette panel panel-info" id="about">
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="Form-section">
          <label class="Form-label--tick col-md-12">
           <div class="col-md-6">
             <img class="img-hov img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url();?>webroot/assets/img/faces/face-2.jpg" id="" height ="120px" width = "120px"  />
            </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
                                   
<input type="radio" id="" name="sen[]" class="Form-label-radio" value="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction()" required = "" />

                                    
 <span class="Form-label-text"></span>
 </label>  
 </div>
</div>
</div> 
                                  
 <h5 class="text text-default">
 <strong> &nbsp;Name:</strong> <?php echo $sen['fullname']; ?><br>
 <strong> &nbsp;Party Name:</strong> <?php echo $sen['party_name']; ?><br>
 <strong> &nbsp;Votes:</strong> <?php echo $sen['votes']; ?></h5>
</div>
</center>
</div>
<?php } ?>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right">Next <i class ="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
     </div>                                 
 </div><br>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

here's my controller where i want to get all its values

```html
public function balot_form(){

    //Senators
       $sen_id = $this->input->post('sen_id[]');   
    $view_sen_votes = $this->vote->view_sen($sen_id);
   
       $data = array("view_sen_votes" => $view_sen_votes);
   
     $this->load->view("admin_dashboard/votation_page/balot_form_page", $data);


}
```

my model

```html
public function view_sen($sen_id){

    $sen_id = implode(', ', $this->input->post('sen_id'));
      
      $this->db->select('*')->from('party_candidates')->where('id', $sen_id);
 
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return $query;
     
}
```

Heres the page where i want to display my selected senators

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <?php foreach($view_sen_votes as $sen) : ?>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group">
    <label>Senators</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $sen['id']; ?>" name="sen_id[]" required="" />
                                                
         </div>        
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
     </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Nobody is going to look into all this code. Specify a particular problem case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**In Controller**

```
public function balot_form(){

    $sen_id[] = $_POST['sen_id'];   
    $view_sen_votes = $this->vote->view_sen($sen_id);       
    $data = array("view_sen_votes" => $view_sen_votes);
    $this->load->view("admin_dashboard/votation_page/balot_form_page", $data);
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function view_sen($sen_id){

    $sen_id[] = $_POST['sen_id']; 
    foreach ($sen_id as $id => $value) {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('party_candidates')->where('id', $value);
        $query[] = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }   
    return $query;                  
}
```

Comment: Hello sir , how to display it in my view? it gives me an error

Comment: Hello sir, ill try your code but it gives me this error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type

Filename: models/vote.php

Line Number: 40

thanks, regards

Comment: @MarkJosephM.Pino what is in line 40??

Comment: this one sir,         $this->db->select('*')->from('party_candidates')->where('id', $sen_id[$id][$value]);

Comment: change this `$sen_id[$id][$value]`  to this `$sen_id[$value]`

Comment: remove all this and add this and `$value`

Comment: how to display it in my view sir? since i have this error , A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: fullname

Filename: votation_page/balot_form_page.php

Line Number: 181

" name="sen_id[]" required="" >

Comment: hello sir please help me... i need this to finishh, its my Thesis Project please sirrr...

Comment: Display in view means??

Comment: @MarkJosephM.Pino ok can you show me your view code??